# Python 3 Calling a method to run inside another method

Tags: python, python-3.x

Apologies beforehand if title does not correctly represent error.

I have a method called ReadChat() which i am trying to call inside a method called SpeechActCounter() as seen below
readfiles.py where ReadChat() is stored:

```
import re
import os

Chatfile = 'ChatLogs/#####/Chat1.txt' 
Lexfile = 'Lexicons/#####.txt'

def ReadChat():
    with open (Chatfile) as file_read:
        chat_content = file_read.readlines()
        for linenum, line in enumerate(chat_content):
            Cleanse = re.sub('<.*?>', '', line)
            print(linenum, Cleanse)            
    file_read.close()

ReadChat()  

def ReadLex():
    with open (Lexfile) as file_read:
        lex_content = file_read.readlines()
        for line in lex_content:
            lex_Cleanse = re.sub(r'^\d+[ \t]+\d+\.\d+%[ \t]*', '', line, flags=re.M)
            lex_Cleanse = os.linesep.join([s for s in lex_Cleanse.splitlines() if s])
            print(lex_Cleanse)


#ReadLex()
```

I am unsure if how i am calling the method is correct inside my main.py

```
    main.py where SpeechActCounter() is stored

    from collections import Counter

from Categories.GainingAccess import GA
from Readfiles import *


SpeechAct = ReadChat()
CategoryGA = GA
Hits = []
cleansedLex = []



def SpeechActCounter():
    Word_Hit = None
    with SpeechAct:
        for line in SpeechAct:
            if any(word in line for word in CategoryGA):
                Word_Hit = False
                for word in CategoryGA:
                    if line.find(word) != -1:
                        Word_Hit = True
                        Hits.append(word)
                        #print('%s appeared on Line' % (word))


count = Counter(Hits)
count.keys()
for key, value in count.items():
    print(key, ':', value)
SpeechActCounter()



def LanguageDetect():
        print('Hello')


#LanguageDetect()
```

Here is the error for which is occurring when i am running my program

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/Lewis Collins/PycharmProjects/######main.py", line 31, in <module>

   SpeechActCounter()

  File "C:/Users/Lewis Collins/PycharmProjects/######/main.py", line 16, in SpeechActCounter
    with SpeechAct:
AttributeError: __exit__
```

Comment: What are you doing?

Comment: `with obj:` requires `obj` to implement the context manager protocol. Since `obj` is just a function in your case, it's an error.

Comment: Either way, please edit your question and *format* the code. Python is super sensitive with indentation; forcing people here to format it is just wrong.

Comment: `ReadChat()` is supposed to return something.

Comment: @Prajwal my Readchat() is the method with cleansed chat file so I'm now trying to call that cleansed version to run my if statement on without having to go through the process of opening the raw one somewhere else to re cleanse

Comment: I would advise loosing a day or half-day learning basic Python. The code posted shows lack of investment into knowing the language basics. Read and execute some tutorials and other materials about the Python fundamentals, and it will go much easier in the future.

Comment: @rl Your comment is not constructive and does not give me a place to start in fixing my current issue